# Remove iframe border

Tags: css, html, iframe

I am using HTML 5 to add a video on to my webpage, with the use of `iframe`. Once I add the video it looks like this below:

[image]

As you can see the black `border`s around the video, is there anyway I can remove that bit and maybe stretch the video across to match up with the `width` of the page?

This is what I have done for displaying the video :

```
<div><iframe src="assets/videos/example.mp4" type="video/mp4" frameBorder="0" width="1280" height="720" allowfullscreen ></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to embed your `iframe` in a responsive way, something like:

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
div {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
```

```html
<div><iframe src='http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4' type="video/mp4" frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Comment: @jomin_george94 can you share the result in a live site?

Comment: After following what you suggested to do, now there is nothing coming up on the screen

Comment: please provide a link with your code instead of just an image

Comment: That was an example with a youtube video, try now because I updated my answer to have a mp4 video, my guess you copy my code and changed the `src`, forgetting to add the `type` (youtube doesn't need)

Answer (score 1):

Remove width and height from iframe and declare it's height and width in CSS.
To match-up with width of your div or browser use `width:100%;`
Add This,

HTML

`<div><iframe src="assets/videos/example.mp4" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe></div>`

CSS

```
div > iframe {width:100%; height:600px;}
```

Height - set your height in pixels, how much you want it to be.